# How to add only missing Dates in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below mentioned data frame:

```
Date        Val1     Val2
2018-04-01  125      0.05
2018-04-03  458      2.99
2018-04-05  354      1.25
```

I want to add only missing dates considering `Sys.Date()` (Here for example `Sys.Date()` is 2018-04-06) in dataframe with corresponding val1 and val2 as 0.

I have tried:

```
t2<-merge(data.frame(Date= seq(min(ymd(t1$Date)), max(ymd(date)), by = "days")), t1, by = "Date", all = TRUE)
```

Required Dataframe:

```
Date        Val1     Val2
2018-04-01  125      0.05
2018-04-02  0        0
2018-04-03  458      2.99
2018-04-04  0        0
2018-04-05  354      1.25
2018-04-06  0        0
```

Comment: BTW, the current date is 2018-05-06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a correction of your approach, in base R.

Replace `max(t1$Date)` by`Sys.Date()` in your real application:

```
t2<-merge(data.frame(Date= as.Date(min(t1$Date):max(t1$Date),"1970-1-1")),
          t1, by = "Date", all = TRUE)
t2[is.na(t2)] <- 0

#         Date Val1 Val2
# 1 2018-04-01  125 0.05
# 2 2018-04-02    0 0.00
# 3 2018-04-03  458 2.99
# 4 2018-04-04    0 0.00
# 5 2018-04-05  354 1.25
```

**data**

```
t1 <- read.table(text="Date        Val1     Val2
'2018-04-01'  125 0.05
'2018-04-03'  458 2.99
'2018-04-05'  354 1.25",h=T,strin=F)
t1$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```

Answer (score 11):

This could be done with `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    complete(Date = seq(Date[1], Sys.Date(), by = "1 day"),
                fill = list(Val1 = 0, Val2 = 0))
```

---

If we need to pass multiple variables for the `fill`, create the list of columns that we need to `fill`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df1), "Date") #in this example excluding the Date
nm2 <- setNames(as.list(rep(0, length(nm1))), nm1)
```

and then pass that as argument for the `fill`

```
df1 %>% 
     complete(Date = seq(Date[1], Sys.Date(), by = "1 day"), fill = nm2)
# A tibble: 35 x 3
#   Date        Val1  Val2
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2018-04-01   125  0.05
# 2 2018-04-02     0  0   
# 3 2018-04-03   458  2.99
# 4 2018-04-04     0  0   
# 5 2018-04-05   354  1.25
# 6 2018-04-06     0  0   
# 7 2018-04-07     0  0   
# 8 2018-04-08     0  0   
# 9 2018-04-09     0  0   
#10 2018-04-10     0  0   
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Comment: If the columns are more than 2 and if don't want to pass all values than is there any way??

Answer (score 4):

You could use `padr`. `padr` is made for filling in missing date values.
First you add the missing dates based on the interval, and if you do not want NA's you fill them with a value (or function of most occuring value)

edit: added end_val to include the run until sys.Date()

```
library(padr)
# Specify end_val to go all the way to sys.Date and add 1 to include sys.Date
padded_df <- pad(df, interval = "day", end_val = Sys.Date()+1)
padded_df <- fill_by_value(padded_df, value = 0)
padded_df

        Date Val1 Val2
1 2018-04-01  125 0.05
2 2018-04-02    0 0.00
3 2018-04-03  458 2.99
4 2018-04-04    0 0.00
5 2018-04-05  354 1.25
.....

31 2018-05-01    0    0
32 2018-05-02    0    0
33 2018-05-03    0    0
34 2018-05-04    0    0
35 2018-05-05    0    0
36 2018-05-06    0    0
```