# Adding missing dates in time series data

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a  data of random dates from 2008 to 2020 and their corresponding value

```
Date                    Val
September 16, 2012       32
September 19, 2014       33
January 05, 2008         26
June 07, 2017            02
December 15, 2019        03
May 28, 2020             18
```

I want to fill the missing dates from January 01 2008 to March 31, 2020 and their corresponding value as 1.

I refer some of the post like [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192024/how-to-add-only-missing-dates-in-dataframe-r), [Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633460/r-fill-missing-dates-by-group) and I am not able to solve the problem based on that. I am a beginner in R.

I am looking for data like this

```
 Date                    Val
 January 01, 2008        1
 January 02, 2008        1
 January 03, 2008        1
 January 04, 2008        1
 January 05, 2008       26
 ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tidyr::complete` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%B %d, %Y")) %>%
  tidyr::complete(Date = seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), as.Date('2020-03-31'), 
                           by = 'day'), fill = list(Val = 1)) %>%
  mutate(Date = format(Date, "%B %d, %Y"))


# A tibble: 4,475 x 2
#   Date               Val
#   <chr>            <dbl>
# 1 January 01, 2008     1
# 2 January 02, 2008     1
# 3 January 03, 2008     1
# 4 January 04, 2008     1
# 5 January 05, 2008    26
# 6 January 06, 2008     1
# 7 January 07, 2008     1
# 8 January 08, 2008     1
# 9 January 09, 2008     1
#10 January 10, 2008     1
# … with 4,465 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("September 16, 2012", "September 19, 2014", 
"January 05, 2008", "June 07, 2017", "December 15, 2019", "May 28, 2020"
), Val = c(32L, 33L, 26L, 2L, 3L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create data frame with the desired date range and then join our data frame on it and replace all `NAs` with 1:

```
library(tidyverse)
days_seq %>% 
  left_join(df) %>% 
  mutate(Val = if_else(is.na(Val), as.integer(1), Val))

Joining, by = "Date"
# A tibble: 4,474 x 2
   Date         Val
   <date>     <int>
 1 2008-01-01     1
 2 2008-01-02     1
 3 2008-01-03     1
 4 2008-01-04     1
 5 2008-01-05    33
 6 2008-01-06     1
 7 2008-01-07     1
 8 2008-01-08     1
 9 2008-01-09     1
10 2008-01-10     1
# ... with 4,464 more rows
```

**Data**

```
days_seq <- tibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2008/01/01"), as.Date("2020/03/31"), "days"))

df <- tibble::tribble(
                   ~Date, ~Val,
        "2012/09/16",  32L,
        "2012/09/19",  33L,
        "2008/01/05",  33L
        ) 
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)
```