# Filling Date Intervals in R

Tags: r

I have a DF with Date_IDs on a monthly basis. As it looks like, there are missing Dates, that I want to fill in in my DF.

```
Test = as.Date(c("2018-08-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-06-01", "2019-08-01","2018-08-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-06-01", "2019-08-01"))
ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
x = data.frame(Test,ID)
```

As you can see in my DF I have missing Dates from 2018-09-01 to 2019-07-01 for each of my IDs.
How can I fill in these Dates, but as well check if the time intervals per ID is complete?

Thanks

Comment: What’s your desired output?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/50192024/680068

Comment: my desired output is check if my ID has the whole date range (from 2018-06-01 to 2019-08-01 on a monthly basis) and if not, then i want to add the missing dates for each ID